# Compare mysql datetime field with php date(Ymd)

Tags: mysql, datetime, null

MySQL DATE_FORMAT returns null value

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(  'stmt_for',  '%Y%m%d' ) FROM  `edu_daily_statements` ;
```

When I run this query MySQL returns null value. The value stored in stmt_for field is `2011-12-06 00:33:40`.

What is the problem?

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(  'stmt_for',  '%Y%m%d' ) = date('Ymd')
```

I need this condition in MySQL query.
Is there any other ways to compare MySQL datetime field `Ymd` with PHP `Ymd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove quotes around `stmt_for`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(stmt_for, '%Y%m%d') FROM  edu_daily_statements;
```

The MySQL function returns a String. You need to convert a PHP date into String as well before you can compare those 2 dates.